# Is Windows 8+ Reset the same as performing a clean install from a MSFT .iso or an OEM .iso?

Tags: windows, security, oem, superfish

Windows 8 and newer versions have a "Windows Reset" feature that reinstalls windows. The question is, does it perform the same kind of clean install that you would achieve with a MSFT .iso, or does it perform a clean install from OEM media, thus keeping all of the crapware?

For example, given the [Lenovo Superfish affair](http://www.theverge.com/2015/2/19/8067505/lenovo-installs-adware-private-data-hackers), will performing a Windows Reset yield a completely clean PC, or will it remove all of your files and apps but keep the crapware?

Comment: The image used by the `Reset` can be modified to restore the device to a default configuration determined by the OEM.  How the `Reset` feature works exactly is well documented on Microsoft's website.

Comment: Maybe it is well documented, but in the pages for end users MSFT doesn't specify this (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc). So I had to ask. And so, in this case, probably reset will keep the crapware. Thanks.

Comment: It depends.  If `Lenovo` updated the image to include the software then it would.  `Reset` replaces all system files and personal files will be lost when used.  It does not use the exact same image as a Windows 8.1 installation .ISO would use though.

Comment: At any rate, we can't trust it (or any other OEM's install image). Thus a clean install is preferable.

Comment: Yet another reason to never buy a pre-installed machine. Thanks for the heads-up.